# Postgres: How to update multiple records in a table with a single command

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, multiple-records

I have a table and I want to update multiple fields to complete the table so all fields are filled, how do I do this in a Postgres script?
As all I can find is how to update one record at a time, or how to loop through and change everything to the same value.

With 100’s of records to update this will take ages

| oid | name | nickname | dob |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Chris | Cross | 01Jan1985 |
| 1 | Richard |  | 02Feb1896 |
| 2 | Michael | Mikey |  |
| 3 | Jonathan |  |  |

Currently I can update one field with the following:

```
    UPDATE mytable SET nickname = 'Rick' Where oid = 1;
```

But how do I do this to change all these?

- nickname = ‘Rick’ where oid = 1
- nickname = ‘Jono’ where oid = 3
- dob = ‘03Mar1987’ where oid = 2
- dob = ‘04Apr1988’ where oid = 3

Thanks in Advance
Daz

Comment: How do you determine which column in which row will receive which value? Are the data in a second table?

Comment: Yes, the data i want loaded into the table is shown in the bullet points

Comment: "With 100’s of records to update this will take ages"  Or at least a substantial fraction of a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UPDATE ... FROM` and join with the new values:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET nickname = coalesce(x.nickname, mytable.nickname)
    dob = coalesce(x.dob, mytable.dob)
FROM (SELECT id,
             max(nickname) AS nickname,
             max(dob) AS dob
      FROM (VALUES (1, 'Rick', NULL),
                   (3, 'Jono', NULL),
                   (2, NULL, '1987-03-03'),
                   (3, NULL, '1988-04-04')) AS y(id, nickname, dob)
      GROUP BY id
     ) AS x
WHERE mytable.id = x.id;
```

Since an `UPDATE` can change each row only once, you have to aggregate by `id`.

Comment: The NULL fields overwrote the data that was already there with empty cells, i.e. removing the data.
I also tried with just removing the NULL but the Update now errors ...
        FROM (VALUES (1, 'Rick', ),

Comment: So to say the above again, it is writing the NULL values to those fields.
Is there a way to have it not process the NULL, or check if there is a value there and if so to not write a NULL value to the table?
Or is there another way of saying NULL but more like skip or ignore?

Comment: Throw in a coalesce, like in my edited answer.